# Убрать анимацию у кнопки в Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

В моём проекте есть объект `Button` следующего вида:

```
<Button
   x:Name="OpenCalc"
   Height="125" 
   Click="OpenCalc_Click" 
   Canvas.Left="-54" 
   Canvas.Top="313" 
   Margin="-55,321,0,326"
   BorderThickness="0">
   <Button.Background>
       <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="calculator_icon.png"/>
   </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

Как видно из кода элемента, я заменил `Background` кнопки на иконку в формате `.png`. При нажатии на неё, ивент отрабатывает как и положено, вызывая метод `OpenCalc_Click`, но сама кнопка на мгновение становится одноцветным прямоугольником - насколько я понимаю, это анимация нажатия кнопки. Как её отключить?

Спасибо.

Comment: Поместите картинку не в `Background`, а в `Content` кнопки. И да, не нужно ставить метку WPF на эти вопросы свои по разработке для WP8.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалось пофиксить заменой элемента `Button` на `Image` с обработчиком событий `Tapped=`:

```
<Image
  x:Name="OpenAdder"
  Height="100" 
  Width="100" 
  Tapped="OpenAdder_Click" 
  Canvas.Left="-55" 
  Canvas.Top="313" 
  Source="calculator_icon.png"/>
```